# Get info about svn root repository structure

Tags: svn

I would like to know how to get information about svn root repository structure using svn api.

I have for instance following structure:

http:/// 

/project1

/project2

I tried :
svn list http:///svn also svn list -v http:///svn

As response I got only : ./

How can I get information recursively ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`svn list` Seems to work for me:

```
tomislav@malik:~$ svn list http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x
.gdbinit
ABOUT_APACHE
Apache.dsw
BuildAll.dsp
BuildBin.dsp
CHANGES
INSTALL
InstallBin.dsp
LAYOUT
LICENSE
Makefile.in
Makefile.win
NOTICE
NWGNUmakefile
README
README-win32.txt
README.platforms
ROADMAP
STATUS
VERSIONING
acinclude.m4
build/
buildconf
config.layout
configure.in
docs/
emacs-style
httpd.dsp
include/
libhttpd.dsp
modules/
os/
server/
srclib/
support/
test/
tomislav@malik:~$
```

The -R flag for recursive listing is also available (see `svn help` list).

Comment: Thank you for response.

I also tried first to get info.

svn info http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x


Repository Root: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf

and than based on repository root tried to display the repository listing using

svn list http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf

In this case it works but in my case I didn't get listing.

Thanks